When does one not need to analyze how their website performs?
Follow-up from What would be the reasons for not using UTM parameters?, I want to focus only to this particular reason for one to not using UTM parameters: They don't define their success on how impact their websites are on the internet.
That excludes these reasons:

They don't know about UTM parameters
The benefit of having web statistics isn't worth the effort
Their main sharing platforms have built-in traffic tracking methods

Why would one make a website and not care about its impact? Can you give some examples?
I'm also thinking of the case that while they do define the success on how their website performs (e.g. total visit, form submission), they don't care about how it is visited by what sources. I can see that in case their target is niche enough that they can estimate the traffic from the sources anyway, then they don't need to know the detail number. But if that's not the case then I don't understand why they don't want to have more data.
The only logical conclusion I have now is that there is simply no-one who makes a website but doesn't define their success on how impact it is on the internet, or who does care about total visit or form submission doesn't care how it is visited by what sources. They don't do that because of the other reasons. I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

The best of the web simply isn't commercial.
People write and make art without caring about what other people think of it.  Or if they do, they'll want to read comments and not care about what screen resolution, browser etc. someone is using.
Likewise, lots of sites are for a known audience - members of a club etc.  They just need a noticeboard for a known audience.
If you ran a forum, you'd care about people posting, but generally wouldn't care about lurkers.
Also, you'd hope people are increasingly aware that it's disrespectful of your users to take more data than you strictly need from them. Marketers should take GDPR seriously, but they rarely do.
There was a web before Analytics. Arguably, a better one.

hmm, this answer doesn't seem to answer about why writers, artists, club or forum founders and managers don't want to analyze how their sites perform, especially on the incoming traffic sources, which is what the UTM parameters are about. In my understanding UTM parameters doesn't violate GDPR at all. Or does it?

To turn your question around - if someone doesn't need to advertise, why would they care about marketing?
Not everything is done for money and growth-at-all-costs optimisation. Most people doing things for fun / small groups simply don't need to run paid adverts etc.  Sites that grow organically can't use UTM, because people who link to your site just because they like it won't add a UTM parameter.
UTM parameters will not violate GDPR by themselves, though if you link that data to a specific user, it may do.  And you'll need that cookie opt-in if you're using GA for a site in the EU.

I think wanting to grow and wanting to maximize money are different things. For example, an academic research project wants to recruit as many participants as possible. Optimizing their traffic source doesn't always mean maximizing the visit count. You can both grow organically and use UTM parameters for the links you seed yourself, right? If one doesn't want to advertise the site, then why do they make it at the first place? (Except when the site is served internally, of course)

what would you say about the cases that the sites are made with the goal to grow their visitors, but they still don't attach the UTM parameters? For example, a seeder who advertises their links on platforms they don't control?

It would depend what they were choosing to measure. Server logs and Session Source / Medium in Analytics can get you good information of where your traffic is coming from.  You need to understand your data and the limitations of that data or else it is meaningless.  Sometimes UTM might be enough for a specific purpose, but it's not particularly more accurate than any other method, and has the disadvantage ugly URLs.  It's not the only way.
